# Setting domain computers Time and Timezone from domain controllers

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, time-synchronization, timezone

I have found that we can set computers in a domain to sync their time from the domain controllers. Similarly, is it possible to centrally manage domain controllers' time zones?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no direct GPO for this, but you can create a Group Policy Registry Preference for this. The key that needs to be set is listed [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/712cc24e-7d32-4860-bf5d-429d6e0fbc79/set-time-zone-using-gpo-in-windows-2008-r2?forum=winserverDS).

Alternatively, you can use `tzutil.exe` which is [documented here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825053.aspx) to set the time zone of computers via a startup script.

The most common way to set the timezone, however, is it configure it in your deployment image. This is typically set in your installation answer file as opposed to after the fact.

Answer (score -1):

Configuring a tz at installation time doesnt work in a multi-tenant rd environment where different domain policy user groups need their own tz.

Comment: The op didn't ask anything about multi-tenant environments.